Proof Fourier single Integral Formula
I was reading Arne Broman's 'Introduction to partial differential equations' and I came accross the proof of Fourier's single integral formula (see photo below for the first page of the proof). When he does triangle inequality and estimates the difference bewteen consecutive integrals he then concludes that $I_5-f<\epsilon$ because of Dirichlet's theorem on the partial sum of a Fourier series. This part is unclear to me. The theorem says that for a periodic function of period 2T, piecewise differentiable, continuous at every point $$s_n(x)=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T}^{T}f(u)\frac{sin((n+\frac{1}{2})\pi\frac{x-u}{T})}{2sin(\pi\frac{x-u}{2T})}du$$ Manipulating the integral for a generic period T I got the following formula that looks more similar to the one usually obtained in the case where the period is $T=2\pi$ (I used the fact that the function we are considering is periodic on the real line with period $T=2a$ and we want to extend this to an arbitrarily large $a$):
$$s_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\frac{au}{\pi}+x)\frac{sin((n+\frac{1}{2})u)}{2sin\frac{u}{2}}du$$ Still I don't see how this can be equal to $I_5$ in the limit $n\to\infty$ (so using the restriction he introduces this also implies $a\to\infty$): I know that the integral I wrote converges to f(x) because I extended f to be periodic on the real line with an arbitrarily large period therefore for his statement to be correct we should also have that $I_5$ converges to my integral in the limit stated above, but that would seem to me as if he had considered the function to have a period of $2\pi$, which is definitely not the case here.
Note: The class DR he mentions at the beginning consists of functions that are integrable, piecewise differentiable and continuous on the real line. So he doesn't even explicitly say that we are considering a periodic function in the proof but I am assuming it is the case otherwise the Dirichlet-formula argument is not valid in general, therefore I am assuming he is considering the function to be periodic in (-a,a) and extending the argument for large values of a.

